# Create a table dynamically in mysql with parameters which I pass as column names

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I want to create a table through stored procedure. I can do it by specifying static column names but I want the column names to be dynamic like arguments which I pass through call method will be column names.

My sample code is this :

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE table_creation(IN column1 VARCHAR(20),IN column2 VARCHAR(20),IN column3 VARCHAR(20),IN column4 VARCHAR(20))
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE mytable(column1 VARCHAR(20),column2 VARCHAR(20), column3 VARCHAR(20), column4 VARCHAR(20));
END $$
DELIMITER;
CALL table_creation(name1,location,working,designation);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find below answer , i hope this will helpful to you.

```
BEGIN
    #Routine body goes here...

                SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = (2056 * 2056);

                            SET @sql = NULL;

                                SET @sql = CONCAT('Create table if not EXISTS my_table (column1 VARCHAR(20),column2 VARCHAR(20), column3 VARCHAR(20), column4 VARCHAR(20)) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ');


                                PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
                                EXECUTE stmt;
                                DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt; 

END
```

Let me know if you fetch any problem.